# for loop over ssh getting unbound variable error

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh

I have below syntax that would compare the modified date of xml files against f1_mdate variable.

```
typeset -f mdate | ssh 101.101.101.101 "cd "$tar_dir"; $(cat); for xml_file in *.xml; do mdate_xml=$(mdate $xml_file) if [[ "$f1_mdate" == "$mdate_xml" ]]; then  echo 1; fi; done"

xml_file: unbound variable
mdate_xml: unbound variable
```

can somebody please help point out why it is getting unbound variable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is quoting; this will be clearer if I put line breaks where the shell sees closing quotes:

```
typeset -f mdate | ssh 10.225.28.45 "cd "\
$tar_dir"; $(cat); for xml_file in *.xml; do mdate_xml=$(mdate $xml_file) if [[ "\
$f1_mdate" == "\
$mdate_xml" ]]; then  echo 1; fi; done"
```

In terms of how to write that correctly... that gets very tricky, because you have two layers of shell which are interpreting commands, stripping quotes and interpolating variables. I usually write a small shell script, scp it to the remote machine and run that remotely, just to get around that... or use a tool like ansible.

As an example of how to get data to and from the remote machine: I created `/tmp/a.sh` on the remote machine `foo`. Here's the content of `/tmp/a.sh`:

```
while read line
do
    echo "xyzzy> $line"
done
```

On my local machine, I have `/tmp/xyz` containing

```
foo
bar
baz
```

Running

```
cat /tmp/xyz | ssh foo bash /tmp/a.sh
```

will give

```
xyzzy> foo
xyzzy> bar
xyzzy> baz
xyzzy>
```

You can re-direct the output to a file:

```
cat /tmp/xyz | ssh foo bash /tmp/a.sh > a.txt
```

The file `a.txt` will be on your local machine.

Comment: How do you get the output of the script you scp? This might be the easiest route for me.